# Message order across rekeying in Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'd like to enrich a topic of data change events (CDC via Debezium) with additional metadata; e.g. say I have a topic of purchase order change events which I'd like to enrich with metadata keyed by the transaction from which the change events originated.

I initially considered to rekey the "purchaseorder" `KStream` by transaction id (which is contained in change events), so I can join it with a `KStream` of the transaction metadata. After enriching the purchase order event with the metadata, I'd rekey it again to the original order id.

But I'm having doubts now that this is going to work as expected: for data change events, retaining the order of events is vital, i.e. for one purchase order (e.g. 123), all events will have the same key (123), thus will go into one partition of the "purchaseorder" topic and in turn will be consumed by clients in the order they were produced.

Now, with the rekeying described above, couldn't it happen that the order of change events for one purchase order gets reshuffled due to the rekeying? One purchase order may be altered by multiple transactions, so IIUC the rekeying via transaction id may cause the events of one purchase order to end up in different partitions, thus voiding the original ordering guarantees.

Which options do I have a this point? I'm contemplating now to avoid the rekey + join and instead implement a manual `transform()` method on the "purchaseorder" stream, which would look up the associated transaction data from a state store. In a scaled Kafka Streams application, that'd imply potential remote look-ups, though, if the transaction data of a given order event is stored on a different node (or using a `GlobalKTable` for the transaction data topic).

Is there any recommendable alternatives?

Comment: Can I ask we don't you partition both topics by purchase order id and use this to add the transaction metadata? Isn't this field available on your transaction metadata stream?

Comment: A transaction may alter multiple tables, e.g. also "customer" or "item", so it cannot be really partitioned by the id of any of the affected tables.

Comment: @Gunnar, in the case where the aggregate is composed of multiple tables you can still put them back together even if they are initially partitioned by their primary key. If they are related one of them will have a foreign key. You then re-partition those messages with that key as they came in and join the two downstream on the right partition. 

This will get an eventually consistent view of the object. If the OP is after some sort of a snapshot for audit, that key may be combined with a tx id and/or lsn offset or something that identifies the transaction.

Comment: No sorry, lsn offset wouldn't be good, maybe tx id and tx time together...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cant you treat the enrichment data as a table? (meaning it will replicate the data to all your processing nodes, allowing you to "enrich in place")

if you cant, and are willing to suffer latency (and have a bound on delays ...)
you could rekey your data (and youre right, since multiple source partitions may now produce data into any target partition reordering may happen), then use an in-memory window to order it back (this is where a bound on delay time becomes critical, and also where latency is introduced) and produce it ordered into yet another topic...

this will be fairly expensive to run this way, and fragile.

Comment: Yes, handling the enrichment data as a GlobalKTable seems to be the only realistic option.

Comment: Is there a recommended approach to mitigating the size of the globalktable? It would seem like this could become sizable given the workload